# Angular2 ngFor - change items order without them being recreated

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, html-rendering

I have quite specific scenario where I have to store state inside of item-components (namely, inside canvas elements) that are being created via ngFor loop.

In my list component I have an array of string ids - and I need to create a canvas element for each id. Afterwards some manipulations can occur with canvas data, so if canvas elements are recreated - pixel data will be lost.

However, sometimes the order of string ids may change and, hence, I would also want to change the order in which ngFor renders those canvas elements. Without actually removing them and creating again.

I know, this scenario might sound weird and there are some other ways to handle what I want but at the moment I'm just interested if this would be possible at all in Angular2/4?.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the object with a `@Pipe`, you just add the pipe to your code, example:

`*ngFor="let field of formFields | keys"`

Where `keys` is a @Pipe.

Check this tutorial for creating a custom `@Pipe`: https://scotch.io/tutorials/create-a-globally-available-custom-pipe-in-angular-2

As you didn't post any code, I assume you have your "change order of elements within object" functionality ready.

So, you could build your `@Pipe` like this:

```
@Pipe({name: 'alterOrder'})
export class AlterOrderPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args: string[]): any {
        let myArray = [];
        for (let elem in value) {
            if (!isNullOrUndefined(elem)) {                    
                // Alter order functionality
                myArray.push(alteredOrderObj);  // alteredOrderObj would be the result of your functionality
            }
        }
        return myArray;
    }
}
```

And in your code, you use it like this:

`*ngFor="let elem of myArray | alterOrder"`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to visually re-order the elements but not re-render them correct? I believe if you don't want to re-render the elements but want them to present in a different visual order, then your best bet is CSS. Maybe use angular to calculate the positioning and then use CSS positioning.

Comment: I know I can do visual reordering with css. But that was not the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `trackBy` of `*ngFor` to control what should re-render. To never re-render anything and just update the order:

```html
<ng-container
  *ngFor="
    let template of orderAlphabetically
      ? [aTmpl, bTmpl, cTmpl]
      : [bTmpl, cTmpl, aTmpl];
    trackBy: trackByFn
  "
>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

where the `trackBy` function goes like this:

```js
trackByFn: TrackByFunction<TemplateRef<unknown>> = (_, value) => value;
```